# Is circular redirect good option when Retry-After is specified?

Tags: http, http-headers, http-redirect

I need to notify client that I want it to revisit the resource in 30 secs because I can't give him satisfactory response immediately.  It's not typical situation, but happens from time to time.

Is 302 redirect with `Retry-After: 30` pointing to the same URL as requested by client header good option?  Or such circular redirects are always bad?

Answer (score 0):

That kind of redirect looping seems like a bad idea to me.

You could just inform the client that they need to initiate a reload. "Sorry, try again later"

Another option to consider is SignalR. By using this, you can automatically update your UI without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

It's a reasonable thing to do; it's the client's responsibility to do loop detection (and HTTP itself talks about this).

James Snell goes into some depth here which might be relevant, depending on exactly what you're trying to do:
  http://chmod777self.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/asynchronous-patterns.html

Answer (score 0):

You can respond with 503 Service Unavailable with a Reply-After that indicates how long until you can provide a satisfactory response. Even though your service is available in a way, it really isn't since it can't provide the required response.